# Footnote on "Contents" at head of table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, footnotes

Is it possible to place a footnote on the **Contents** heading that is generated at the head of a table of contents? (Not on an individual item in the table of contents, as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6319/adding-notes-to-table-of-contents).)

I thought perhaps `titletoc` would permit this, but I see nothing about footnotes in the docs for that package.

---

**Edit**: I am using document class `scrbook` (needed for `\multiplefootmarker`, since the author's notes use numbers, while the editor's notes use * and other symbols). It is the editor who needs to annotate the **Contents** title.

Comment: What document class are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1. `book` class

#### Method 1 — Define a new command

The `\ftableofcontents` command wants as argument the text of the footnote.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand\ftableofcontents{\renewcommand\ftableofcontents[1]}
\expandafter\ftableofcontents\expandafter{\tableofcontents}
\xpatchcmd\ftableofcontents
  {\contentsname}
  {\contentsname\footnote{#1}\fi}{}{}
% Omit the following lines if you want the footnote with an arabic number
\xpretocmd\ftableofcontents{\begingroup\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}{}{}
\xapptocmd\ftableofcontents{\endgroup}{}{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\ftableofcontents{This is the footnote}

\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
Here is a footnote\footnote{A}
\end{document}
```

#### Method 2 — Overload `\tableofcontents`

In this case we redefine `\tableofcontents` to accept as optional argument the text of the footnote; nothing happens if no optional argument is specified.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand\temp{\renewcommand\tableofcontents[1][]}
\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\tableofcontents}
\xpatchcmd\tableofcontents
  {\contentsname}
  {\contentsname\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\footnote{#1}\fi}{}{}
% Omit the following lines if you want the footnote with an arabic number
\xpretocmd\tableofcontents{\begingroup\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}{}{}
\xapptocmd\tableofcontents{\endgroup}{}{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents[This is the footnote]

\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
Here is a footnote\footnote{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## 2. `scrbook` class

The previous methods don't work with the `scrbook` class and it would be *very* difficult to patch the commands that produce the table of contents, so a hack seems the best thing to try (apart avoiding putting a footnote to a chapter title to begin with).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\protected@edef\contentsname{\contentsname\unexpanded{\footnote{%
  %%%% ADD HERE THE FOOTNOTE TEXT
  This is a footnote%
  %%%% DON'T FORGET THE FINAL %
  }}%
  \gdef\noexpand\contentsname{\contentsname}}

% Omit the following line if you want a number
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\mainmatter
```

## 3. Alternative method (all classes)

Instead of a footnote you can add some text just after the header.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\addtocontents{toc}{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{{%
  \itshape\footnotesize
  This is a note for the table of contents
  \par\bigskip
}}}}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this (updated (thrice) to take into account `egreg` remarks)

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\let\oldcontentsname\contentsname
\let\myif\iftrue
\def\myfootnotemark{\global\let\myif\iffalse\footnotemark}

\renewcommand\contentsname{\oldcontentsname\myif\myfootnotemark\fi}

\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\footnotetext{this is my footnote}}


\section{First}

\subsection{A}

\subsection{B}

\section{Two}

\subsection{C}

\section{First}

\subsection{A}

\subsection{B}

\section{Two}

\subsection{C}

\section{First}

\subsection{A}

\subsection{B}

\section{Two}

\subsection{C}

\section{First}

\subsection{A}

\subsection{B}

\section{Two}

\subsection{C}

\section{First}

\subsection{A}

\subsection{B}

\section{Two}

\subsection{C}

\section{First}

\subsection{A}

\subsection{B}

\section{Two}

\subsection{C}

\section{First}

\subsection{A}

\subsection{B}

\section{Two}

\subsection{C}



\end{document}
```

[image: first page of output]

Comment: If the TOC has more than one page ...

Comment: @egreg thanks for making me address this possibility. See the updated answer.

Comment: The footnote mark will be added also to the headers.

Comment: @egreg see updated updated answer.

Comment: it could be that in the code above `\global\let\myif\iffalse` would be better than `\let\myif\iffalse`, but as `TeX` is an experimental science for me and as it worked in my test file,  I am leaving things like this ... until someone points out some flaw arising in more complicated situations.

Comment: Yes, the problem was exactly to emit the footnotemark only once. With `\global` it's certainly better.

Comment: `\global` added.