# How to highlight a Section

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I'm writting some math notes and I want to highlight some sections (analogously chapters, subsections,...) in the ToC (and as well in the regular text).

By "highlight" I mean, put some symbol next to the section title (or near) so the reader can notice (maybe by a footnote) that these parts of the text are, one way or another, special.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6325/101651, I think it could be useful for you.

Comment: This is rather something for `tocloft` and `\cftpresecnum` etc. ... for special cases, however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method that appends a small symbol after the page number to the ToC if the switch `\importantstuff` has been used. This persists until `\unimportantstuff` is applied.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}% For scalebox
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo} % For 'funny' logos

\newif\ifimportantstuff
\newlength\pnumcontentskip

\setlength{\pnumcontentskip}{1.5em}% control the distance after the page number

\DeclareRobustCommand{\importantstuffsymbol}{\hskip\pnumcontentskip\scalebox{0.4}{\bcattention}}

\newcommand{\afterpnumcontent}{\ifimportantstuff\importantstuffsymbol\else\phantom{\importantstuffsymbol}\fi}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\cftchapafterpnum\afterpnumcontent
\g@addto@macro\cftsecafterpnum\afterpnumcontent
\g@addto@macro\cftsubsecafterpnum\afterpnumcontent
\g@addto@macro\cftsubsubsecafterpnum\afterpnumcontent
\g@addto@macro\cftparaafterpnum\afterpnumcontent
\g@addto@macro\cftsubparaafterpnum\afterpnumcontent
\makeatother


% Switch the usage on 
\newcommand{\importantstuff}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\global\string\importantstufftrue}%
}

% Switch the usage off
\newcommand{\unimportantstuff}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\global\string\importantstufffalse}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}

\importantstuff
\section{Foo section}

\section{Foobar section}

\subsection{Foobar subsection}


\unimportantstuff

\section{More foobar, but not important}

\importantstuff
\chapter{More important content}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update -- with some configurable interface.

Use `\RedeclareStructureCommands` to enable or `\RedeclareStructureCommands*` to disable the feature.

The default state of an entry is 'unimportant', the symbols can be changed with `tocsymbol` and the note is given with `tocsymbolnote`.

Scale the symbols size with any other value than `0.4` in the `\tocsymbol`, `\inlinesymbol` and `\emptytocsymbol` macros.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}% For scalebox
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo} % For 'funny' logos


\usepackage{xparse}

\providecommand{\localtocsymbol}{}
\providecommand{\localtocsymbolcommand}{}


\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn


\seq_new:N \l_alvaro_structurecommands_seq 

\prop_new:N \l_alvaro_highlight_prop

\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_alvaro_structurecommands_seq  { part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph , subparagraph }


\keys_define:nn {alvarohighlight}{%
  tocsymbol .code:n={ \cs_set_nopar:Npn \localtocsymbolcommand {#1}
    \bool_set_false:N\l_alvaro_unimportant_bool
  }
  ,
  tocsymbolnote .code:n= { \prop_put:Nnn \l_alvaro_highlight_prop {note} {#1}},
  unimportant .code:n={ \cs_gset_nopar:Npn \localtocsymbolcommand {}
    \bool_set_true:N\l_alvaro_unimportant_bool
    \prop_remove:Nn \l_alvaro_highlight_prop {note} 
  }
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\SetupHighlighting}{}{%
% For later purposes
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SetupHighlightingOptions}{+O{}}{%
  \bool_set_true:N \l_alvaro_unimportant_bool
  \keys_set:nn {alvarohighlight} {unimportant,#1}
  \SetupHighlighting
}

\cs_new:Nn \alvaro_pretoc_entry:n {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_alvaro_unimportant_bool { %  
    % Write dummy to toc
    \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\string\renewcommand{\string\localtocsymbolcommand}{\bccrayon}\string\renewcommand{\string\localtocsymbol}{\emptytocsymbol\protect\phantom{1}}}}
  {%
    \prop_if_in:NnTF \l_alvaro_highlight_prop {note} {%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\string\renewcommand{\string\localtocsymbolcommand}{#1}\string\renewcommand{\string\localtocsymbol}{\tocsymbol\protect\footnote{\prop_item:Nn \l_alvaro_highlight_prop {note}}}}
    }{%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\string\renewcommand{\string\localtocsymbolcommand}{#1}\string\renewcommand{\string\localtocsymbol}{\tocsymbol\protect\phantom{1}}}
    }
  }% End of \bool_if
}

\cs_new:Nn \alvaro_posttoc_entry:n {
  \addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\RedeclareStructureCommands}{s}{%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_alvaro_structurecommands_seq {%
    \cs_set_eq:cc { latex@@##1 } {##1} 
    \expandafter\RenewDocumentCommand\csname ##1\endcsname{somO{}}{%
      \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn {alvarohighlight} {unimportant,####4}
      \SetupHighlighting
      \IfBooleanTF{####1}{%
        \use:c{latex@@##1*}{####3}
      }{%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
          \IfValueTF{####2}{%
            \use:c{latex@@##1}[####2]{####3}
          }{%
            \use:c{latex@@##1}{####3}
          }%
        }{%
          \alvaro_pretoc_entry:n { \localtocsymbolcommand }
          \IfValueTF{####2}{%
            \use:c{latex@@##1}[####2]{\texorpdfstring{####3\inlinesymbol}{####3}}
          }{%
            \use:c{latex@@##1}[####3]{\texorpdfstring{####3\inlinesymbol}{####3}}
          }%
          \alvaro_posttoc_entry:n {}
        }
      }
      \group_end:
    }
  }% End of \seq_map_inline
}




\ExplSyntaxOff


\newif\ifimportantstuff
\newlength\pnumcontentskip

\setlength{\pnumcontentskip}{1.5em}% control the distance after the page number

\newcommand{\afterpnumcontent}{\localtocsymbol}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\cftchapafterpnum\afterpnumcontent
\g@addto@macro\cftsecafterpnum\afterpnumcontent
\g@addto@macro\cftsubsecafterpnum\afterpnumcontent
\g@addto@macro\cftsubsubsecafterpnum\afterpnumcontent
\g@addto@macro\cftparaafterpnum\afterpnumcontent
\g@addto@macro\cftsubparaafterpnum\afterpnumcontent
\makeatother


%%% User code!

% Use the starred version to switch off the symbols and notes
%\RedeclareStructureCommands*

% Use the unstarred version to enable the symbols and notes
\RedeclareStructureCommands


\SetupHighlightingOptions[tocsymbol={\bcbombe},unimportant]

\DeclareRobustCommand{\tocsymbol}{\hskip\pnumcontentskip\scalebox{0.4}{\protect\localtocsymbolcommand}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\inlinesymbol}{\marginpar{\scalebox{0.4}{\localtocsymbolcommand}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\emptytocsymbol}{\hskip\pnumcontentskip\scalebox{0.4}{\phantom\localtocsymbolcommand}}




\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}[tocsymbol={\bcbombe},tocsymbolnote={Dangerous additions}]

\section{Foo section}[unimportant]

\section{Foobar section}[tocsymbol={\bccrayon}, tocsymbolnote={Edited}]

\subsection{Foobar subsection}
\section{More foobar, but not important}

\chapter{More important content}[tocsymbol={\bcrecyclage},tocsymbolnote={Reworked}]

\section{Added}[tocsymbol={\bctrombone},tocsymbolnote={Added}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Amazing! I just have one little problem with the answer, and is that there is that no symbol is displayed in the regular text (only in the ToC). In addition (not really important), the solution doesn't provides a way to insert a footnote (or similar) in the ToC so the reader cand understand the meaning of the symbol.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Tenorio: I'll try to update

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Tenorio: See a possible update ... not perfect, but better than before